# Unable to display background image in email

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, sendmail, sendgrid

I have a `.tpl` template to which I feed data and is sent through email to consumer, but in email I'm not getting background image, though I have debugged the request and got html going in `sendEmail` function, saved that in an html file and that is showing the background image but not in email. I am using SMPT of send grid for sending mails. here is css where I'm setting background image:

```
body {
        background-image: url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/7d4c51bf7e89c06d7cbf03ed5/images/37260602-46f7-4061-bfad-43d962150495.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: bottom center;
    }
```

does it has to do something **sendgrid's SMTP Server**? or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: try inline css ?

Comment: Email only works with `inline-css` as far as I know

Comment: Jep, inline css needed for most of the email programms

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS in html background is displayed correctly once a consumer receives email, it is without background.

Comment: ok @Cleancode let me check

Comment: Thanks everyone, inlince css worked perfectly.

Comment: @MianMuhammad I have added the answer kindly check :) happy to help

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS checked and upvoted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email clients are kinda tricky when it comes to styling and displaying things. More "ancient" methods have to be used
You could try as a fallback along with your inline css, the following:

```
background="URL" width="yourWidth" height="yourHeight" valign="top/bottom"
```

Comment: as described in comments, inline css actually worked

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need to add the inline css.

Try updating your css as inline like shown below

```
background="URL"
```